# How to get INSERT errors from $wpdb?

Tags: mysql, wpdb, sql

I have these

```
    $wpdb->suppress_errors(false);
    $wpdb->show_errors (true);

    $wpdbp = $wpdb->prepare($preparedQuery->query, $preparedQuery->values);
    $result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdbp);
```

I further thought of something like this (may be temporary)

```
    if($result === null) {
        $error = $wpdb->print_error();
        var_dump($error);
      }
```

I read in `get_var()` documentation:

> Returns: Database query result (as string), or null on failure

My problem here is that `$result` is always null when inserting, even if insert succeeds.
How to actually know it there were errors or not?
I expect there may be some other types of `get_` methods?

Maybe I sould add something like "SELECT 1;" but even if that works I don't like it much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert data you should use `query()` ([documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries)), `get_var()` method is for selecting data. If error is encountered, `query()` returns FALSE.

> **query()**
>
> This function returns an integer value indicating the number of rows affected/selected for SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, etc.
>
> For CREATE, ALTER, TRUNCATE and DROP SQL statements, (which affect whole tables instead of specific rows) this function returns TRUE on success. If a MySQL error is encountered, the function will return FALSE.

```
$result = $wpdb->query( 'insert query' );
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    // display error
}
```